# Add bitmap image from video list

Tags: android, listview, bitmap

I tried to make a list of videos, everything was right, the list is shown and you can see in videoview. but.
1) How can I add bitmap image in the list of videos?
2) How can I change the ListView, with Gridview?

Thank you

Videoscan code:

```
public class VideoScan extends AppCompatActivity{

    private Cursor videocursor;
    private int video_column_index;
    ListView videolist;
    int count;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_video_scan);
        init_phone_video_grid();
    }

    private void init_phone_video_grid() {
        System.gc();
        String[] proj = { MediaStore.Video.Media._ID,
                MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA,
                MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
                MediaStore.Video.Media.SIZE };
        videocursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                proj, null, null, null);
        count = videocursor.getCount();
        videolist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.PhoneVideoList);
        videolist.setAdapter(new VideoAdapter(getApplicationContext()));
        videolist.setOnItemClickListener(videogridlistener);
    }

    private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener videogridlistener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position,
                                long id) {
            System.gc();
            video_column_index = videocursor
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA);
            videocursor.moveToPosition(position);
            String filename = videocursor.getString(video_column_index);
            Intent intent = new Intent(VideoScan.this, ViewVideo.class);
            intent.putExtra("videofilename", filename);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    };

    public class VideoAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private Context vContext;

        public VideoAdapter(Context c) {
            vContext = c;
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return count;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            System.gc();
            TextView tv = new TextView(vContext.getApplicationContext());
            String id = null;
            if (convertView == null) {
                video_column_index = videocursor
                        .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME);
                videocursor.moveToPosition(position);
                id = videocursor.getString(video_column_index);
                video_column_index = videocursor
                        .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.SIZE);
                videocursor.moveToPosition(position);
                id += " Size(KB):" + videocursor.getString(video_column_index);
                tv.setText(id);
            } else
                tv = (TextView) convertView;
            return tv;
        }
    }
```

xml

```
    <ListView
    android:id="@+id/PhoneVideoList"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

Comment: "How can I add bitmap image in the list of videos?" -- use an image-loading library. In [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Media/VideoList), I use Universal Image Loader.

Comment: I have a lot of errors with this sample,

Comment: thos sample is work. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified this s[ample](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware), and go now. Thank @commonsware who advised me.